# Amazon Product api Browse Node ID for japan is not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

```
$request = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?" .
       "Service=AWSECommerceService" . 
       "&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup" .
       "&BrowseNodeId=465610" . 
       "&MerchantId=All" . 
       "&Condition=All" . 
       "&Availability=Available" . 
       "&Sort=salesrank" . 
       "&Version=$this->version" . 
       "&AssociateTag=$this->associateTag" . 
       "&BrowseNode=17".
       "&SearchIndex=Books" . 
       "&ResponseGroup=TopSellers";
```

I receive this response(below) when sending my request(above):

```
<Message>
BrowseNodes is not a valid value for ResponseGroup. Please change this value and retry your request.
</Message>
```

`BrowseNodeId 465610` is the id for books in japan as you can see here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html

Why am I having these problem? Any idea guys?

P.S:

The $request above is the unprocessed one, when processed it's working, the response is in xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$uri = "http://webservices.amazon.co.jp/onca/xml?" .
                "Service=AWSECommerceService" .
                "&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup" .
                "&MerchantId=All" .
                "&Condition=All" .
                "&Sort=salesrank" .
                "&Version=$this->version" .
                "&AssociateTag=$this->associateTag" .
                "&SearchIndex=Books" .
                "&BrowseNodeId=465610" .
                "&ResponseGroup=TopSellers";
```

Try that, you don't need the BrowseNode, it will only limit the records you get to the browsenode 17 which is Literature & Fiction, and that is on US, not on jp, I don't know if it's different in jp.